# How to adaptively adjust performance to CPU usage?

Tags: multithreading, performance, process, boinc

there. I don't even know if this question makes sense, however: how do BOINC-based applications adapt their performance so that they only use "free" CPU, without affecting the execution of user's applications?

Thank you,
Tunnuz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They set their process priority to the same as the idle thread?

In windows [SetPriorityClass()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS:

> Process whose threads run only when the system is idle. The threads of the process are preempted by the threads of any process running in a higher priority class. An example is a screen saver. The idle-priority class is inherited by child processes.

[More about scheduling priorities in windows here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they just set the priority of their computation thread(s) to something very low, and then rely on the OS's scheduler to do the rest.  Threads/processes with a low priority will only run when no other threads need the CPU time for anything.